# Can Ruby read a .dat file created in VB.NET?

Tags: ruby, vb.net, visual-studio

How would I create a list of elements in VB.NET, save it to a .dat file, and make Ruby re-create such list (as an array) with such elements (they will be strings, booleans and integers)?

Comment: Ruby can read a .dat file, but unless you describe the inner data format of the file it will be a string of bytes, which won't mean much. If you describe the data being saved then answers can be more meaningful, such as *how* to read the data and turn it into Ruby objects. A short answer is Ruby supports `unpack` which is the gateway to reading all sorts of formats. If you serialize the data as XML, YAML or JSON it would be easier to move the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but you'd need to find some representation for it.  The easiest is probably JSON, so you would

1. make the data structure in VB
2. write it to JSON as a file
3. read the JSON file using Ruby.

Here's a [JSON serializer](http://json.codeplex.com/) for .Net:

Comment: It seems JSON creates a nice human-readable text string, which is pretty cool. But, are there any other options for making it non-human-readable?

Comment: Okay, I will give it a go soon.

Answer (score 1):

A .dat file is just a binary blob, 'tis it not? If there's any particular format you use you could easily translate that to equivalent Ruby code. Just as long as the knowledge is duplicated on both ends, though that leads to a violation of the DRY principle. JSON might be a good intermediate representation (as noted by @Charlie Martin) because it's a plain text format and you can always add compression.